# Unable to setup redmine in my local system with XAMPP

Tags: web, server, xampp, localhost, redmine

I am trying to setup redmine in my local system with XAMPP. But I could see only the files and directories in 'http://localhost/redmine'  I've setup redmine and I have tested the installation by running WEBrick web server, everything works fine. Anyone let me know what to do.

[image: Screenshot of http://localhost/redmine]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not sure which OS you are running:

If you are running on Windows than I would suggest to first try with the Bitnami Stack which has everything ready made as an installer (https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/installer).
Installing all the necessary prerequisites on Windows can be a major pain for someone new to the topic of installing ruby on rails.

If you are running on Linux it is relatively easy as you basically just need to add passenger to your apache (Tutorials here -> https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/apache/oss/install_passenger_main.html)

Comment: I'm running on windows. Yes, I tried the bitnami redmine stack. Sure it is a saver.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is for PHP, Redmine is written in Ruby (Ruby on rails). If you need an local devel setup, I highly recommend to run Docker container.